# Trying to select button and frame with Xpath on google plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

I am trying to automate a task using Google plus circles. The program I'm using uses xpath to target the right element in order to click a button.

However, I'm not able to select the right target since Google seems to use some advanced anti scraping measures (that's my interpretation of the situation anyhow, but I'm really on a junior level on xpaths).

[Example page:](https://play.google.com/store/people/details?id=117591579984474297830)

My task is to select the add to cirkles, by first clicking the button and then clicking one of the alternatives. **In order to see the button you have to be logged in to Google plus by the way.**

I've tried some xpaths already, which have not worked:

**Attempt one:** 
First click: `//div[@id='contentPanel']//div` 
Second Click: `//div[@id=':4o.lbl']//div`

**Attempt Two:** 
First Click: `//*[@id="root"]/div/div` 
Second Click: `//div[@id=':4o.lbl']//div`

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Best regards, CnapBack

Comment: I suspect part of the reason you haven't gotten an answer yet is that people have to log in to Google Plus to see the HTML, and even then, there's no guarantee that we will see the same content (e.g. same ID's) as you are. I would suggest (1) checking that Google Plus is actually delivering the same ID's to you every time you attempt the task; (2) telling us what program you're using XPath in, which will help nail down what variety of XPath it is; and (3) putting a relevant sample of the HTML in your question.

Comment: P.S. You could also let us know what the results of your attempts were. Do they all select zero nodes? Does the first click sometimes select an element but the second doesn't?